# Android Cancel Notification From Backend

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I noticed that some app like messenger clear their notification in phone even I viewed the message from web.I know it can be done by giving ID to notification when showing it and when it needs to be cleared we can send another event via FCM and clear the corresponding notification. Is there a proper way of doing it other than sending another event via FCM because it feels not the proper way of doing it for me.